# what is the best way to compress/decompress data within a solidity smart contract?

Tags: solidity, rollups, l2

I'm working on a l2 optimistic rollup academic project (thesis), where the sequencer would submit the compressed txs as calldata. At a dispute (aka a different post-state), a verifier would challenge the tx batch but he needs to first verify the tx batch is the same as sequencer submitted batch.
Only possible way of doing this is first decompressing the tx batch in L1 in the smart contract then calculating the batch hash (say keccak256(txbatch)) against the verfier submited tx batch's hash.

Comment: Does this help: https://github.com/clabby/op-kompressor/blob/main/README.md ?